# Starting to study the Model Theory

Tags: reference-request, model-theory, book-recommendation

I would like to start studying Model Theory and I would like some suggestions of books. And I would like to know: Is it better to make a mathematical logic review after start model theory?

Comment: Regarding books, see books that I really recommend in my answer. i have to admit that I don't understand your point *Is it better to make a mathematical logic review after start model theory?*

Comment: It is because I first saw model theory studying the consistency of the CH and the book I read made some review in logic and in the part of the proof the author use Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem which seems to be Related with logic. Then I thought that maybe a good way to start studying model theory would be by doing a review in mathematical logic. This what I mean.

Comment: There are many similar questions on this site already: here [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/161924/7062) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/746617/7062) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3813071/7062) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/883038/7062) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/997034/7062).

Comment: Yes, I am starting to use this social media and now I realized that have some similar questions about this topic. Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

- [Model theory by Chang / keisler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486488217)
- [Model theory: an introduction by Marker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387987606)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

[A Course in Model Theory, by Tent and Ziegler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052176324X)